# Integral over a Jordan curve

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I've got the task:

Let $C$ be a Jordan curve, piecewise smooth. Compute $\int_C \frac{e^z}{z(1-z)^3} dz$, if:

a)$z_0 = 0$ is inside $C$, and $z_1 = 1$ outside.

b) both $z_0$ and $z_1$ are outside of $C$.

Well, how to work with it? If those points were inside, it would look like Cauchy integral theorem, but if one of them/ both are outside...? Then what can I do? May you help? I have no idea, even how to begin, which theorems I should use, nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part $a$, only $z_0$ lies inside, so let $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{(1-z)^3}$.  The integral is now

$$\int_C\frac{f(z)}{z}dz$$ where we can use the Cauchy Integral Formula.

Use the same logic for part $b$.

Comment: So I get in a) $2\pi i$ and $0$ in b)? Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are!  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

In the first situation use the Residues and in the second the integral is $0$ 'cause $\frac{e^z}{z(1-z)^3}$ is holomorhic inside $C$